# How retrieve ID from link?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm working on a website with PHP and Javascript.
What I so far did is list all the rows from my PhpAdmin database. For each of these row, I have a reply link. For example a person leave a message and as the message is listed on my page I have a reply link on the bottom right. The thing is I can have like 200 rows. 
What I try to do is create a link for each "reply" link in a while loop so that when I click the link it will open a new page with the good question text.
My problem is I can't seem to find how to get the good message (either by ID from the database or the link I created in the loop).

```
<?php
            // Connexion à la base de données

        include("BDConnect.php");


        $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM table_commentaires');

            // On affiche chaque entrée une à une
        while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
        {
            ?>
            <p>

            <li><p><em>From: <?php echo $donnees['pseudo'] ?> </em><br>
              <?php echo $donnees['comm'] ?> </p></li> 
              <a href = "#">
                <reps><?php echo "Répondre" ?></reps>
            </a>
            <br>
        </p>

                <?php
            }

                $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête


                ?>
```

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Just added the code. I'm stuck here @LegoStormtroopr

Answer (score 1):

if i understood that correctly, you have a loop, and for each iteration, you have the entire row (and maybe the row id, if your query was correct), then you generate each element (lets say a div), you can do something like this:

`<a href="http://localhost/site/?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>">`

so each link its diferent :)

Comment: How can you know this will answer the askers question, when they have shown zero code? How do you know they have a column `id` in their table?

Comment: I've added the code that lists each row from the database. And no I dont have a column id in my table. I assumed that PhpMyAdmin will assign it automatically (autoincrement)... @Chichozell

Comment: Well, if you read muy answer again i said that maybe she will get the row id, i was trying to show her everything that she needs to get this to work

Comment: Meliss, to do that you would have to add a new column called ID and add auto_increment attribute to that columnas so you dont hace to assign a id each time you sabe a new row

Answer (score 1):

You will have to setup a column in phpMyadmin. This could be a Primary Key (PK) and set that to auto incrementing (AI). After every row that gets inserted, this field should be incremented by 1.

The 'reps' tag must be something new because I've never heard of it.

In your php code instead of using

```
<a href = "#">
    <reps><?php echo "Répondre" ?></reps>
</a>
```

try

```
echo '<a href=somepage.php?id=' . $row['yourPK'] . '>' .$row['yourPK']. '</a>';
```

You will have to edit it a bit to suit your needs, but it will display an href to the comment.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that ! The reps tag is just for my css stylesheet, not a real tag